# Has the formula for "interesting" questions recently changed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, interesting-page

I'm used to the default SO page having lots of questions with yellow backgrounds, meaning they're questions with tags that I've expressly said I'm interested in.  Today, I'm seeing very few of those.  Did something change?

Comment: We've deployed a few fixes here - no changes were intentional to behavior, only unfortunate side-effects of some caching removal. After some Saturday night deploy action to fix this up, it should be behaving correctly now.

Answer (score 21):

#### TL;DR

https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

All of the issues happened in legacy code which hasn't changed in years. It wasn't using our standard caching primitives, and porting it to our <strike>new</strike> modern [caching primitives](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/739767093621600256) opened up a can of worms.

---

Upon first inspection, nothing changed directly in the logic. What changed is how we handle caching around it, which is causing this bug.

A fix for this has been deployed in build rev `2019.9.28.35054`.

> It was caused by a singleton class call that was hidden a few frames down in the call stack. The affected class depended on the current http request being around implicitly, but failed silently when it wasn't. The http request was not in the call context anymore, because the interesting posts are now being fetched in a background/worker thread.

---

That didn't completely fix the issues, upon more reports and another careful inspection of the code, we found another bug which got fixed in build rev `2019.9.29.35057`.

> There was another oversight, which passed multiple code reviews. We didn't introduce caching per-se, we only changed what (lists of post ids instead of HTML) gets cached, and how the values get fetched. Cache keys generation didn't change at all, which turned out to be a landmine #1, because a special cache key (`null`) was non-obviously used to tell the old caching code to *not cache* the values. The new code however silently swallowed / used the null key and did cache.

Comment: Nice explanation. +1