# Why am I seeing questions with ignored tags?

Tags: support, tags

Without any settings change on my part (to the best of my knowledge) I am now seeing questions on my feed in a grayed-out form that have tags from my ignore list. This is new after years of seeing it work correctly. I have also not been able to find any setting that disables their display.

I have found a "duplicate" question concerning a different forum but the answer it leads to is many years old and references an invalid URL as a fix.

Comment: On the home page? or the questions page.

Comment: Thank God. I thought it was just me and I was losing my mind. A huge portion of my homepage was questions with .35 opacity. If you edit your ignored tags you should see an options to hide them. On a side note, my home page seems to be filled with way more questions I don't care about than the ones I'm watching. Something changed.

Comment: because whatever is happening here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389861/has-the-formula-for-interesting-questions-recently-changed might be related.

Comment: Home page, at least.  I'm used to just clicking the stackoverflow icon at the top/left of the page to refresh a filtered list.

Comment: I can improve the situation by creating a custom filter that requires my watched tags and using that instead of the main page.  It still doesn't honor ignored tags, however, for cases where both are present.